# White page with async EnterHook in React Router while hydrating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using an async enterhook in my root react-routerv3 route to authentify the user. I've already read about that using async enterhooks isn't recommended, but I don't think that the reasons for this recommendation are my problem.

I hydrate my server-side rendered DOM and everything works fine, if I don't use a callback inside my onEnter function. As soon as I'm fetching some content inside it, my server-side rendered content gets thrown away and a rendering of my App component happens, when the callback of onEnter gets resolved. It seems to ignore the fact, that I use hydrate, to only rerender differences.

```
const onEnter = (next, redirect, callback) => {
  if (auth.notLoggedIn) {
    return callback(); // works fine or I don't notice any flickering
  }

  return auth
    .login()
    .then(callback) // full App rerender
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);

      return callback(); // full App rerender
    });
}

const App = () => <Route onEnter={onEnter}>asdf</Route>;

ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, myMountPoint);
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what 'full page rerender' means. Does `App` rerender? Or `Route`? Or the whole HTML page reloads? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that replicates the problem. If you're able to mock SSR response and put it to Stackblitz or else, this may work.

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to recreate a whole example, that is able to show my problem. However, App does rerender, it's not a classical page reload. I'm using hydrate in my entrypoint, to only "rerender" differences, but it seems that using an EnterHook in React Router, triggers a rerender for the whole App component.

Comment: A router doesn't have control over <App>, I would expect this only for <Route>. In your example they are literally same. I assume route re-rendering is how onEnter works. They probably got rid of it because it wasn't good enough, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4976 . I'm not sure if there are other approaches, but a reasonable one is to wait until async dependencies are ready before initializing the app, i.e. `doInitialAuth.then(() => ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, myMountPoint))`. Or before initializing the router.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's the only sane way. Thank you!

Comment: It works this way, I'm really thankful! :)

Comment: Consider posting the solution you ended up with as an answer. Self-answers are welcome on SO. This may help somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async EnterHooks seem to ignore the hydration mode. I came up with a workaround like this:

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  if (auth.notLoggedIn) {
    return resolve();
  }

  return auth
    .login()
    .then(resolve)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);

      return resolve();
    });
}).then(() => {
  const App = () => <Route>asdf</Route>;

  ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, myMountPoint);
});
```

Props to [estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus)!